# Laravel Newly created seeder does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have a new Laravel Seeder but is giving a class does not exist error. The said seeder works in my **local machine** but not in **production**. The only file that I pushed was the seeder file itself.

File is in `database\seeders`

Filename: `SeederName.php`

Here is the code structure:

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Model1;
use App\Models\Model2;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class SeederName extends Seeder
{}
```

When I run the command  `php artisan db:seed --class=SeederName`, it returns a   `Target class [Database\Seeders\SeederName] does not exist.`

One of the top answers given was to run the command `composer dump-autoload` However, when I run the said command, I am getting a `Class Database\Seeders\SeederName located in ./database/seeders/SeederName.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.`

My composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    },
},

"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

I also compared this new seeder with my other seeder file and code structure is the same.

Comment: What EXACTLY name of seeder php file? It must be named EXACTLY as class name

Comment: Yes I used the same name. I typed is as case sensitive.

Comment: I also used the same command that was used in my local to my production down to the last letter. My expected result should have been the same with my local since there was nothing that really changed since I pushed the file.

Comment: Hmm, check the `autoload-dev` section in `composer.json` - if there is same autoloaders (seeders) - try to delete and `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: @Maksim I updated my question and added the seeder file name

Comment: I added the autoload-dev. the composer.json is the same with local

Comment: BTW it is `php artisan db:seed` not seeder.

Comment: sorry typo. But still the same.

Comment: This seems to be in order. You may have a typo in your class or filename. Hard to tell if your question uses example names.

Comment: I pushed the same file to repo so the production should have the same file. I also checked in repo(double click the file) and the file is the same. Used the same command to run the seeder class but still getting this issue.

Comment: Rerun again the same seeder with the same command in my local machine and it is running without an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but when I create a new seeder, now it works. Everything is the same except for the File Name and Class Name.